# After successful cashfree payment email/sms send not working properly (codeigniter 3)

Tags: php, codeigniter, cashfree

After successful payment (cashfree test environment) I am reducing stocks from database, sending email & sms to vendor regarding order received & stock reduced as well as to customer regarding order placed. (email & sms).

The problem I am facing is vendor receiving email/sms infinity times, also same with the customer & stock keeps reducing automatically with each email/sms vendor & customer receives.

Receiving email/sms each 5min, 15 mins, 1hr interval. For one order 5 to 6 email/sms in some time intervals.

I don't know how its automatically works like a cron job or something.

Need help in this. Below is the reference code for the issue.

```html
**Page: payment-checkout.php (view)**

<body onload="document.frm1.submit()">
<form action="<?php echo $url; ?>" name="frm1" method="post">
      <p>Please wait.......</p>
      <input type="hidden" name="signature" value='<?php echo $signature; ?>'/>
      <input type="hidden" name="orderNote" value='<?php echo $post_data['orderNote']; ?>'/>
      <input type="hidden" name="orderCurrency" value='<?php echo $post_data['orderCurrency']; ?>'/>
      <input type="hidden" name="customerName" value='<?php echo $post_data['customerName']; ?>'/>
      <input type="hidden" name="customerEmail" value='<?php echo $post_data['customerEmail']; ?>'/>
      <input type="hidden" name="customerPhone" value='<?php echo $post_data['customerPhone']; ?>'/>
      <input type="hidden" name="orderAmount" value='<?php echo $post_data['orderAmount']; ?>'/>
      <input type ="hidden" name="notifyUrl" value='<?php echo $post_data['notifyUrl']; ?>'/>
      <input type ="hidden" name="returnUrl" value='<?php echo $post_data['returnUrl']; ?>'/>
      <input type="hidden" name="appId" value='<?php echo $post_data['appId']; ?>'/>
      <input type="hidden" name="orderId" value='<?php echo $post_data['orderId']; ?>'/>
      <input type ="hidden" name="coupon_discount" value='<?php echo $post_data['coupon_discount']; ?>'/>
      <input type="hidden" name="total_price" value='<?php echo $post_data['total_price']; ?>'/>
      <input type="hidden" name="coupon_id" value='<?php echo $post_data['coupon_id']; ?>'/>
  </form>
    </body>
```

```php
Here is the complete code from my controller

function cashfree_payment() {
        $user_id = $_SESSION['userdata']['user_id'];
        $session_id = $_SESSION['session_data']['session_id'];
        $deliveryaddress_id = $this->input->post('address_id');
        $payment_option = "";
        $order_id = "AM" . rand(111111111, 999999999);
        $grand_total = $this->input->post('totalAmount');
        $coupon_id = $this->input->post('coupon_id');
        $coupon_code = $this->input->post('coupon_code');
        $coupon_disount = $this->input->post('coupon_discount');
        $gst = $this->input->post('gst');
        $created_at = time();
        $order_status = 1;

        $chk = $this->Web_model->doOrder($session_id, $user_id, $deliveryaddress_id, $payment_option, $created_at, $order_status, $grand_total, $order_id, $coupon_id, $coupon_code, $coupon_disount, $gst);

        if (is_array($chk)) {
            if ($chk['status'] == '@success') {
                $order_details = $this->Web_model->orderDetails($chk['order_id']);
                $mode = "TEST"; //<------------ Change to TEST for test server, PROD for production
                //extract($_POST);
                $secretKey = TEST_SECRET_KEY;
                $postData = array(
                    "appId" => TEST_APP_ID,
                    "orderId" => $order_id,
                    "orderAmount" => $grand_total,
                    "orderCurrency" => DEFAULT_CURRENCY,
                    "orderNote" => 'ORDER',
                    "customerName" => $order_details['ordersdetails']['customer_name'],
                    "customerPhone" => $order_details['ordersdetails']['mobile'],
                    "customerEmail" => $order_details['ordersdetails']['email'],
                    "returnUrl" => base_url('web/do_cashfree_order'),
                    "notifyUrl" => base_url('web/do_cashfree_order'),
                    "coupon_discount" => $coupon_disount,
                    'total_price' => $grand_total,
                    'coupon_id' => $coupon_id
                );

                //pr($postData);
                ksort($postData);
                $signatureData = "";
                foreach ($postData as $key => $value) {

                    $signatureData .= $key . $value;
                }
                $signature = hash_hmac('sha256', $signatureData, $secretKey, true);
                $signature = base64_encode($signature);

                if ($mode == "PROD") {
                    $url = "https://www.cashfree.com/checkout/post/submit";
                } else {
                    $url = "https://test.cashfree.com/billpay/checkout/post/submit";
                }

                $this->load->view('web/includes/payment-checkout', ['post_data' => $postData, 'signature' => $signature, 'url' => $url]);
            }
        }
    }

    function do_cashfree_order() {

        $secretkey = TEST_SECRET_KEY;
        $orderId = $_POST["orderId"];
        $orderAmount = $_POST["orderAmount"];
        $referenceId = $_POST["referenceId"];
        $txStatus = $_POST["txStatus"];
        $paymentMode = $_POST["paymentMode"];
        $txMsg = $_POST["txMsg"];
        $txTime = $_POST["txTime"];
        $signature = $_POST["signature"];
        if ($txStatus == "SUCCESS") {
            $trans_status = 1;
        } else {
            $trans_status = 0;
        }

        $data = $orderId . $orderAmount . $referenceId . $txStatus . $paymentMode . $txMsg . $txTime;

        $hash_hmac = hash_hmac('sha256', $data, $secretkey, true);
        $computedSignature = base64_encode($hash_hmac);
        if ($signature == $computedSignature) {
            $insert['pay_orderid'] = $orderId;
            $insert['payment_option'] = $paymentMode;
            $insert['transaction_time'] = $txTime;
            $insert['pay_transaction_id'] = $referenceId;
            $insert['payment_status'] = $trans_status;
            $insert['order_status'] = 2;
            if ($txStatus == "SUCCESS") {
                $update_order_transaction = $this->Web_model->update_order_transaction($insert);
                if ($update_order_transaction) {
                    $id = ($this->common_model->get_data_row(['pay_orderid' => $orderId], 'orders'))->id;
                    $order_details = $this->Web_model->orderDetails($id);

                    //sms send to customer
//                    $phone = $order_details['ordersdetails']['mobile'];
//                    $otp_message = "Dear " . $order_details['ordersdetails']['customer_name'] . ", your order with order ID #" . $order_details['ordersdetails']['id'] . " placed successfully. Thank you for shopping. In case of any queries pls contact customer care. Thanks and Regards";
//                    $template_id = '1407165995915174281';
//                    $this->Web_model->send_message($otp_message, $phone, $template_id);
                    //sms send to vendor (check if multiple vendors)
//                    $vendor_mobile = ($this->common_model->get_data_row(['id' => $order_details['ordersdetails']['vendor_id']], 'vendor_shop'))->mobile;
//                    $vendor_otp_message = "Dear vendor thank you for accepting order no #" . $order_details['ordersdetails']['id'] . " & pls prepare goods as requested and pack them for delivery. Thanks and Regards";
//                    $vendor_template_id = '1407165996082020881';
//                    $this->Web_model->send_message($vendor_otp_message, $vendor_mobile, $vendor_template_id);
                    //email send

                    $subject = $this->data['order_placed_invoice']->subject;
                    $title = $this->data['order_placed_invoice']->title;
                    $message = $this->data['order_placed_invoice']->message;
                    $footer = $this->data['order_placed_invoice']->footer;

                    $message .= '<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Invoice</title>
        <style>
            .clearfix:after {
                content: "";
                display: table;
                clear: both;
            }

            a {
                color: #5D6975;
                text-decoration: underline;
            }

            body {
                position: relative;
                width: 21cm;
                height: auto;
                margin: 0 auto;
                color: #001028;
                background: #FFFFFF;
                font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
                font-size: 12px;
                font-family: Arial;
            }

            header {
                padding: 10px 0;
                margin-bottom: 30px;
            }

            #logo {
                text-align: center;
                margin-bottom: 10px;
            }

            #logo img {
                width: 90px;
            }

            h1 {
                border-top: 1px solid  #5D6975;
                border-bottom: 1px solid  #5D6975;
                color: #5D6975;
                font-size: 2.4em;
                line-height: 1.4em;
                font-weight: normal;
                text-align: center;
                margin: 0 0 20px 0;
                background: url(' . base_url('web_assets/img/') . 'dimension.png);
            }

            #project {
                float: left;
            }

            #project span {
                color: #5D6975;
                text-align: right;
                width: 87px;
                margin-right: 10px;
                display: inline-block;
                font-size: 0.9em;
            }

            #company {
                float: right;
                text-align: right;
            }

            #project div,
            #company div {
                white-space: nowrap;
            }

            table {
                width: 100%;
                border-collapse: collapse;
                border-spacing: 0;
                margin-bottom: 20px;
            }

            table tr:nth-child(2n-1) td {
                background: #F5F5F5;
            }

            table th,
            table td {
                text-align: center;
            }

            table th {
                padding: 5px 20px;
                color: #5D6975;
                border-bottom: 1px solid #C1CED9;
                white-space: nowrap;
                font-weight: normal;
            }

            table .service,
            table .desc {
                text-align: left;
            }

            table td {
                padding: 20px;
                text-align: right;
            }

            table td.service,
            table td.desc {
                vertical-align: top;
            }

            table td.unit,
            table td.qty,
            table td.total {
                font-size: 1.2em;
            }

            table td.grand {
                border-top: 1px solid #5D6975;
                ;
            }

            #notices .notice {
                color: #5D6975;
                font-size: 1.2em;
            }

            footer {
                color: #5D6975;
                width: 100%;
                height: 30px;
                position: absolute;
                bottom: 0;
                border-top: 1px solid #C1CED9;
                padding: 8px 0;
                text-align: center;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header class="clearfix">
            <div id="logo">
                <img src="' . base_url('uploads/images/') . $this->data['site']->logo . '">
            </div>
            <h1>[ ' . $title . ' ]</h1>
            <div id="company" class="clearfix">
                <div>' . $order_details['ordersdetails']['customer_name'] . '</div>
                <div><a href="mailto:' . $order_details['ordersdetails']['email'] . '">' . $order_details['ordersdetails']['email'] . '</a></div>
                <div>' . $order_details['ordersdetails']['mobile'] . '</div>
                <div>' . $order_details['ordersdetails']['useraddress'] . '</div>
            </div>
            <div id="project">
                <div><span>Order ID</span> #' . $order_details['ordersdetails']['id'] . '</div>
                <div><span>Placed On</span> ' . $order_details['ordersdetails']['created_date'] . '</div>
                <div><span>Payment Status</span> ' . $order_details['ordersdetails']['payment_status'] . '</div>
                <div><span>Payment Method</span> ' . $order_details['ordersdetails']['payment_type'] . '</div>
                <div><span>Order status</span> ' . $order_details['ordersdetails']['order_status'] . '</div>    
            </div>
        </header>
        <main>
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="service">#</th>
                        <th class="service">Product</th>
                        <th class="desc">Product Name</th>
                        <th class="desc">Price</th>
                        <th class="desc">Quantity</th>
                        <th class="desc">Total</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>';

                    $count = 1;
                    foreach ($order_details['ordersdetails']['cartdetails'] as $item) {

                        $message .= '<tr>
                            <td class="service">' . $count . '</td>
                            <td class="service"><img src ="' . $item['image'] . '" style="width:50px;height:50px" /></td>
                            <td class="desc">
                                ' . $item['productname'] . '<br>
                                [' . ucfirst($item['attributes'][0]['attribute_type']) . ': ' . $item['attributes'][0]['attribute_values'] . ']
                            </td>
                            <td class="desc">' . DEFAULT_CURRENCY . '. ' . $item['price'] . '</td>
                            <td class="desc">' . $item['quantity'] . '</td>
                            <td class="desc">' . DEFAULT_CURRENCY . '. ' . $item['total_price'] . '</td>

                        </tr>';
                    }
                    $message .= '<tr>
                        <td colspan="5">Subtotal</td>
                        <td class="total">' . DEFAULT_CURRENCY . '. ' . $order_details['ordersdetails']['sub_total'] . '</td>
                    </tr>';
                    if (!empty($order_details['ordersdetails']['coupon_disount'])) {
                        $message .= '<tr>
                        <td colspan="5">Coupon Discount</td>
                        <td class="total">(' . DEFAULT_CURRENCY . '. ' . $order_details['ordersdetails']['coupon_disount'] . ')</td>
                    </tr>';
                    }

                    if (!empty($order_details['ordersdetails']['deliveryboy_commission'])) {
                        $message .= '<tr>
                        <td colspan="5">Delivery Charge</td>
                        <td class="total">' . DEFAULT_CURRENCY . '. ' . $order_details['ordersdetails']['deliveryboy_commission'] . '</td>
                    </tr>';
                    }

                    if (!empty($order_details['ordersdetails']['gst'])) {
                        $message .= '<tr>
                        <td colspan="5">GST</td>
                        <td class="total">' . DEFAULT_CURRENCY . '. ' . $order_details['ordersdetails']['gst'] . '</td>
                    </tr>';
                    }

                    if ($order_details['ordersdetails']['gst'] == "") {
                        $gst = 0;
                    } else {
                        $gst = $order_details['ordersdetails']['gst'];
                    }

                    $sub_coupon = ($order_details['ordersdetails']['sub_total'] - $order_details['ordersdetails']['coupon_disount']);
                    $order_boy = ($order_details['ordersdetails']['deliveryboy_commission'] + $gst);
                    $final_total = $sub_coupon + $order_boy;

                    $message .= '<tr>
                        <td colspan="5" class="grand total">GRAND TOTAL</td>
                        <td class="grand total">' . DEFAULT_CURRENCY . '. ' . $final_total . '</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </main>
        <footer>
            ' . $footer . '
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>';

                    //send mail to customer

                    $config1['protocol'] = MAIL_PROTOCOL;
                    $config1['smtp_host'] = MAIL_SMTP_HOST;
                    $config1['smtp_port'] = MAIL_SMTP_PORT;
                    $config1['smtp_timeout'] = '7';
                    $config1['smtp_user'] = MAIL_SMTP_USER;
                    $config1['smtp_pass'] = MAIL_SMTP_PASS;
                    $config1['charset'] = MAIL_CHARSET;
                    $config1['newline'] = "\r\n";
                    $config1['mailtype'] = 'html'; // or html
                    $config1['validation'] = TRUE; // bool whether to validate email or not      

                    $this->email->initialize($config1);

                    $this->email->from(MAIL_SMTP_USER, $this->data['site']->seo_title);
                    $this->email->to($order_details['ordersdetails']['email']);
                    $this->email->subject($subject);
                    $this->email->message($message);

                    if ($this->email->send()) {
                        echo '@success';
                    } else {
                        echo '@error';
                    }

                    //Manage stock here
                    $vendor_quanity_arr = [];
                    $user_id = $order_details['ordersdetails']['user_id'];
                    $session_id = $order_details['ordersdetails']['session_id'];
                    $cart = $this->common_model->get_data_with_condition(['user_id' => $user_id, 'session_id' => $session_id], 'cart');
                    foreach ($cart as $value) {
                        array_push($vendor_quanity_arr, ['variant_id' => $value->variant_id, 'quantity' => $value->quantity]);
                    }

                    $stockObj = json_decode(json_encode($vendor_quanity_arr));

                    //send notification to vendor regarding stock reduce
                    foreach ($stockObj as $row) {
                        $row->variant = $this->common_model->get_data_row(['id' => $row->variant_id], 'link_variant');
                        $row->product = $this->common_model->get_data_row(['id' => $row->variant->product_id], 'products');
                        $product_image = $this->common_model->get_data_row(['variant_id' => $row->variant_id], 'product_images')->image;
                        $row->product_image = base_url('uploads/products/') . $product_image;
                        $row->vendor = $this->common_model->get_data_row(['id' => $row->product->shop_id], 'vendor_shop');
                        $row->stock_left = (int) $row->variant->stock - (int) $row->quantity;
                        $attribute = (json_decode($row->variant->jsondata))[0];
                        $row->attr_title = $this->common_model->get_data_row(['id' => $attribute->attribute_type], 'attributes_title')->title;
                        $row->attr_value = $this->common_model->get_data_row(['id' => $attribute->attribute_value], 'attributes_values')->value;

                        $ar = array('varient_id' => $row->variant_id, 'product_id' => $row->variant->product_id, 'quantity' => $row->quantity, 'paid_status' => 'Debit', 'message' => 'New Order', 'total_stock' => $row->stock_left, 'created_at' => time());

                        $ins11 = $this->db->insert("stock_management", $ar);

                        if ($ins11) {
                            $this->db->update("link_variant", array('stock' => $row->stock_left), array('id' => $row->variant_id));
                        }

                        //check stock limit set
                        $stock_limit = $this->data['site']->stock_limit;
                        if ($row->stock_left <= $stock_limit) {

                            $subject = 'Stock Deducted';
                            $message = 'Dear Vendor,<br>';
                            $message .= 'Find out the stock details for your product ID: #' . $row->product->id . '<br>';
                            $message .= '<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Invoice</title>
        <style>
            .clearfix:after {
                content: "";
                display: table;
                clear: both;
            }

            a {
                color: #5D6975;
                text-decoration: underline;
            }

            body {
                position: relative;
                width: 21cm;
                height: auto;
                margin: 0 auto;
                color: #001028;
                background: #FFFFFF;
                font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
                font-size: 12px;
                font-family: Arial;
            }

            header {
                padding: 10px 0;
                margin-bottom: 30px;
            }

            #logo {
                text-align: center;
                margin-bottom: 10px;
            }

            #logo img {
                width: 90px;
            }

            h1 {
                border-top: 1px solid  #5D6975;
                border-bottom: 1px solid  #5D6975;
                color: #5D6975;
                font-size: 2.4em;
                line-height: 1.4em;
                font-weight: normal;
                text-align: center;
                margin: 0 0 20px 0;
                background: url(' . base_url('web_assets/img/') . 'dimension.png);
            }

            #project {
                float: left;
            }

            #project span {
                color: #5D6975;
                text-align: right;
                width: 87px;
                margin-right: 10px;
                display: inline-block;
                font-size: 0.9em;
            }

            #company {
                float: right;
                text-align: right;
            }

            #project div,
            #company div {
                white-space: nowrap;
            }

            table {
                width: 100%;
                border-collapse: collapse;
                border-spacing: 0;
                margin-bottom: 20px;
            }

            table tr:nth-child(2n-1) td {
                background: #F5F5F5;
            }

            table th,
            table td {
                text-align: center;
            }

            table th {
                padding: 5px 20px;
                color: #5D6975;
                border-bottom: 1px solid #C1CED9;
                white-space: nowrap;
                font-weight: normal;
            }

            table .service,
            table .desc {
                text-align: left;
            }

            table td {
                padding: 20px;
                text-align: right;
            }

            table td.service,
            table td.desc {
                vertical-align: top;
            }

            table td.unit,
            table td.qty,
            table td.total {
                font-size: 1.2em;
            }

            table td.grand {
                border-top: 1px solid #5D6975;
                ;
            }

            #notices .notice {
                color: #5D6975;
                font-size: 1.2em;
            }

            footer {
                color: #5D6975;
                width: 100%;
                height: 30px;
                position: absolute;
                bottom: 0;
                border-top: 1px solid #C1CED9;
                padding: 8px 0;
                text-align: center;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header class="clearfix">
            <div id="logo">
                <img src="' . base_url('uploads/images/') . $this->data['site']->logo . '">
            </div>
            <h1>Stock Notification</h1>
        </header>
        <main>
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="service">#</th>
                        <th class="service">Product</th>
                        <th class="desc">Product Name</th>
                        <th class="desc">Total Stock</th>
                        <th class="desc">Stock Deducted</th>
                        <th class="desc">Final Stock</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                            <td class="service">1</td>
                            <td class="service"><img src ="' . $row->product_image . '" style="width:50px;height:50px" /></td>
                            <td class="desc">
                            ' . $row->product->name . '<br>
                                [' . ucfirst($row->attr_title) . ': ' . $row->attr_value . ']
                            </td>
                            <td class="desc">' . $row->variant->stock . '</td>
                            <td class="desc">' . $row->quantity . '</td>
                            <td class="desc">' . $row->stock_left . '</td>

                        </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </main>
    </body>
</html>';

                            $config1['protocol'] = MAIL_PROTOCOL;
                            $config1['smtp_host'] = MAIL_SMTP_HOST;
                            $config1['smtp_port'] = MAIL_SMTP_PORT;
                            $config1['smtp_timeout'] = '7';
                            $config1['smtp_user'] = MAIL_SMTP_USER;
                            $config1['smtp_pass'] = MAIL_SMTP_PASS;
                            $config1['charset'] = MAIL_CHARSET;
                            $config1['newline'] = "\r\n";
                            $config1['mailtype'] = 'html'; // or html
                            $config1['validation'] = TRUE; // bool whether to validate email or not      

                            $this->email->initialize($config1);

                            $this->email->from(MAIL_SMTP_USER, $this->data['site']->seo_title);
                            $this->email->to($row->vendor->email);
                            $this->email->subject($subject);
                            $this->email->message($message);

                            $this->email->send();
                        }
                    }

                    $sess_arr_old = array(
                        'session_id' => false,
                        'session_status' => false
                    );

                    $this->session->unset_userdata('session_data', $sess_arr_old);
                    $user_id = $this->db->get_where('orders', ['pay_orderid' => $orderId])->row()->user_id;
                    $user_data = $this->db->get_where('users', ['id' => $user_id])->row();
                    $sess_arr = array(
                        'user_id' => $user_id,
                        'email' => $user_data->email,
                        'phone' => $user_data->phone,
                        'logged_in' => true
                    );
                    $this->session->set_userdata('userdata', $sess_arr);

                    $session_id = rand(11111111111111, 99999999999999);
                    $sess = array(
                        'session_id' => $session_id,
                        'session_status' => true
                    );
                    $this->session->set_userdata('session_data', $sess);

                    redirect('web/thankYou');
                }
            } else {
                $user_id = $this->db->get_where('orders', ['pay_transaction_id' => $orderId])->row()->user_id;
                $user_data = $this->db->get_where('users', ['id' => $user_id])->row();
                $sess_arr = array(
                    'user_id' => $user_id,
                    'email' => $user_data->email,
                    'phone' => $user_data->phone,
                    'logged_in' => true
                );
                $this->session->set_userdata('userdata', $sess_arr);

                $session_id = rand(11111111111111, 99999999999999);
                $sess = array(
                    'session_id' => $session_id,
                    'session_status' => true
                );
                $this->session->set_userdata('session_data', $sess);

                $this->db->where('pay_transaction_id', $orderId)->delete('orders');
                redirect('web/failure_cashfree');
            }
        }
    }

    function failure_cashfree() {
        $this->load->view("web/includes/header_styles", $this->data);
        $this->load->view('web/includes/payment_failure');
        $this->load->view("web/includes/footer", $this->data);
    }
```

Comment: If you're using the free version, maybe they have limitations. Recheck it.

Comment: You should post the code that sends the email and sms as well, or we have no idea how/what you're actually doing. The posted code doesn't even do anything other than just defining some variables and hash some data. Not sure what you hope we can do here?

Comment: I have updated the post. Hope, it's understandable now. @m-eriksson

Comment: @ChandanKumarNayak I am from cashfree payments. Would like to understand this problem further. Can you share the title of the email you are receiving

Comment: Not really a helpful comment, but I still want to give you a heads-up that if you need to specify 12 variables at the start of your function, you might want to consider breaking up the function into smaller sections. This will greatly improve the ability to debug.

Comment: @RajNandanSharma sir.. I am not receiving any email from cashfree. It's the email format I am attaching to send to customers & vendors after a successfull order. Not only email, also it's deducting stocks from database multiple time. Same code works fine if I put after COD order successfull. But here it's not working properly. Getting one mail 10 times a day & stocks reducing multiple. May be I am doing something wrong or it's a issue in payment gateway no idea about that.

Comment: @KayAngevare I tried so many ways. Exact code works perfectly fine if I put after COD successfully placed but in cashfree 20 times same order placed mail I am receiving in 24hrs. After 1hr or 2hr gap. It's keeps coming.

Comment: can you change the code if ($txStatus == "SUCCESS") { to if ($txStatus == "SUCCESS" && yourTable.order.status == 'paid') {

Comment: @ChandanKumarNayak I do not question your intentions, but having a single function span 600+ (!) lines is worrying to say the least. I suggest you divide it into smaller sections / methods and use some template imports because this is near impossible to debug.